# how to crawl a login protected site or page?

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I want to crawl a site, which is required access to see pages. I am able to crawl guest pages, but how to crawl login protected pages?
It will be great if somebody share steps to configure or skip the authentication mechanism to crawl a page using storm crawler.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can use the requests module (python) and use the class Session to manage a session with login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the following keys with their corresponding values in the configuration of your topology

```
http.basicauth.user
http.basicauth.password
```

See [WIKI page](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Configuration#fetching-and-partitioning) on configuration